# Pathfinder unite is coming out jagged

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

This has never happened before and it's driving me insane. I'm merging perfectly aligned elements and when I do the rounded edge comes out jagged. Any ideas?

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: after]

Outline
[image: outline]

After outline
[image: after outline]

Comment: Is it possible that there are hidden objects behind the round one that are jagged? Can you include a screenshot in outline mode

Comment: Fisrt things first disable the GPU preview and use CPU preview.

Comment: I've added the outline. There isn't anything else that could be causing the jaggedness. I've used CPU preview and it does the same thing.

Comment: How does the outline look _after_ you unite? Does it create additional anchors for all those jagged spots?

Comment: @Luciano it does add extra anchor points.

Comment: If you create an entirely new document, and try to repeat, do you get the same result? Also, try resetting Illustrator Preferences. I've had some really weird issues in the past that just starting with a new document helps.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey I tried that as well. That usually fixes it to try the opposite file. Like print instead of web, etc. Might be some dumb bug. Going to try and re-download and try again.

Answer (score 1):

On the **Pathfinder Panel Menu** choose `Pathfinder Options`.

You may need to alter the default settings....

Here's what I use, may or may not help you:

[image]

Also, ensure `Align to Pixel Grid` isn't on.

Comment: I have .028, but yes this seems to be the only option.

Comment: .028 is the default I believe. If that's what you have.. I would strongly suspect align to pixel grid settings.

Comment: @Scott Unfortunately that didn't work. It's really strange because I've known about the align to pixel grid back when was added to the transform box. It's no longer there but at the top right mini menu. It's turned off. I just kind of think it's some strange bug. Might try and delete and re-download illustrator.